# Re-stacking MovieClips in an Array

Tags: actionscript-3, multidimensional-array, stack, movieclip

I was trying to make a similar thing with the game SameGame (ie. the block above the removed blocks fall downward). Before trying this with an Array that contains MovieClips, this code worked (tried it with int values). With MovieClips on the array, it seems not working the same way.

With int values, example:

```
popUp(0, 4): Before: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10; After: 1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10
```

But with MovieClips:

```
popUp(0, 4): Before: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10; After; 1,2,3,4
// Assume the numbers are movieclips XD
```

Basically, it strips everything else, rather than just the said block >_<

Here's the whole method. Basically, two extra arrays juggle the values above the soon-to-be removed value, remove the value, then re-stack it to the original array.

What could be wrong with this? And am I doing the right thing for what I really wanted to emulate?

```
function popUp(col:uint, row:uint)
    {
        var tempStack:Array = new Array();
        var extraStack:Array = new Array();
        tempStack = IndexArray[col];
        removeChild(tempStack[0]);
        for(var ctr:uint = tempStack.length-(row+1); ctr > 0; ctr--)
        {
            removeChild(tempStack[ctr]);
            extraStack.push(tempStack.pop());
            trace(extraStack);
        }

        tempStack.pop();

        for(ctr = extraStack.length; ctr > 0; ctr--)
        {
            tempStack.push(extraStack.pop());
            //addChild(tempStack[ctr]);
        }

        IndexArray[col] = tempStack;
    }
```

PS: If it's not too much to ask, are there free step-by-step guides on making a SameGame in AS3 (I fear I might not be doing things right)? Thanks in advance =)

Comment: I'm finding it hard to decipher what you want to achieve. Could you explain using more English and less code? I can provide lots of help in terms of saving locations of MovieClips and loading them back later if that's the goal :)

Comment: Ummm, I don't know if this will help: Imagine a stack of different books, stacked vertically. Now, Imaging taking a book between the stack. What I really wanted is that the desired book is taken, and the others above it remains in the stack.

EDIT: I think your answer is enough =)

Comment: Sounds like you simply want to remove an element and re-shift everything down? There's an inbuilt method for this: will answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want to remove an element and have everything after that index shift down a place to fill what you removed. There's an inbuilt function for this called `splice(start:uint, length:uint);`

Parameters:
**start** - the index to start removing elements from
**length** - the amount of elements to remove

```
var ar:Array = ["hello","there","sir"];

ar.splice(1, 1);
```

ar is now -> ["hello", "sir"];

---

As per question:

Here's an example with different types of elements:

```
var ar:Array = [new MovieClip(), "some string", new Sprite(), 8];
ar.splice(2, 1);

trace(ar); // [object MovieClip], some string, 8
```

And further example to display the indexes being changed:

```
trace(ar[2]); // was [object Sprite], is now 8
```

Comment: Will this work with MovieClips? And will the indices (is this the plural of index?) of the values after the spliced value change? If yes, thanks! =) EDIT: Forgot to ask, sorry. How will the syntax be if I will use this in a two-dimensional Array?

Comment: Yep. splice re-indexes everything after what you've removed :)

Comment: You are awesome! Thanks! Now, I might post a different question if I can't make the grid display upside-down without an infinite loop XD